# Django and python-twitter error

Tags: django, twitter, python-twitter

I'm trying to send my title post to twitter. In my local machine, this is working great, but in the remote machine, I have this error from the snippet file:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

I'm using [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) and [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1339/). I don't know why the error is being thrown. I tested the `python-twitter` with commands like `import twitter` and I sent the post to twitter from the python shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a project recently.  Do you have a folder in your application directory named twitter or a file named twitter.py?  A file or folder in your application directory can create a conflict with the python-twitter library.

Answer (score 0):

Either installation is not proper. Anyway , take look at the documentation at http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/